# Why are some functions omitted in `dir()` output?

Tags: python, pycharm

In the Python console started by PyCharm, it looks like `runfile` is an imported function:

```
In[21]: runfile
Out[21]: <function _pydev_bundle.pydev_umd.runfile(filename, args=None, wdir=None, is_module=False, global_vars=None)>
```

Since it's a name in the local scope, shouldn't it be listed in `dir()`'s output?

```
In[22]: print(dir())
['In', 'Out', '_', '_12', '_13', '_14', '_15', '_16', '_17', '_18', '_19', '_21', '_3', '_5', '_6', '_7', '_8', '__', '___', '__builtin__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_dh', '_i', '_i1', '_i10', '_i11', '_i12', '_i13', '_i14', '_i15', '_i16', '_i17', '_i18', '_i19', '_i2', '_i20', '_i21', '_i22', '_i3', '_i4', '_i5', '_i6', '_i7', '_i8', '_i9', '_ih', '_ii', '_iii', '_oh', 'a', 'absolute', 'exit', 'get_ipython', 'numpy', 'quit', 'sys']
```

Comment: I now see this in the Python tutorial: `dir() does not list the names of built-in functions and variables.` `import builtins; dir(builtins)` shows these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Because `runfile` is made as a built-in, just like `dir()` itself.

If `dir()` without argument can list all available calls, it should list itself too...

Python shell will search for the name not only in local scope, but also in built-in module.

You can find both `dir` and `runfile` in `dir(__builtin__)`.